# List view from join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, foreign-keys, join

A has_many joined database as shown

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :people, through: :years 
end

class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :address
  belongs_to :person
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :years, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :addresses, through: :years    
end
```

I'm having trouble with the list view for Years, i.e., `Views>Years>list.html.erb`

Here's a sample of what doesn't work:

```
# table headers here
<% @years.each do |y| %>
   <tr>
     <td><%= y.year_date %></td>
     <td><%= y.person_id %></td>
     <td><%= y.person.given_name %></td>
     <td><%= y.person.last_name %></td>
    ...
<% end %>
```

`year_date` is the date that the person what at the address and displays fine if the `given_name` and `last_name` lines aren't present.
And `year.person_id` displays just fine too.
But `year.person.given_name` and `year.person.last_name` do not display. `given_name` and `last_name` are a fields in the Person table.

The error is `undefined method given_name for nil:NilClass`.

Obviously a bit of a noob or this would be more obvious. Part of the problem may be in how to phrase the search.

Complete code here: https://bitbucket.org/MtnBiker/crores5

Thanks for suggestions. Been looking for days.

Edit: Looking around started wondering about foreign keys and here's what I found in the database via pgAdmin.

```
ALTER TABLE people
  ADD CONSTRAINT fk_rails_56c79562d9 FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
      REFERENCES addresses (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

Edit 2. Add controller:

```
class YearsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
  before_action :set_year, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @years = Year.all
    @years = Year.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
  end
```

Schema?

```
CREATE TABLE years
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  year_date date,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  resto boolean,
  resid boolean,
  source text,
  person_id integer,
  address_id integer,
  title character varying,
  CONSTRAINT years_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_rails_8fc1813509 FOREIGN KEY (person_id)
      REFERENCES people (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT fk_rails_e1624dbb3f FOREIGN KEY (address_id)
      REFERENCES addresses (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE years
  OWNER TO gscar;

-- Index: index_years_on_address_id

-- DROP INDEX index_years_on_address_id;

CREATE INDEX index_years_on_address_id
  ON years
  USING btree
  (address_id);

-- Index: index_years_on_person_id

-- DROP INDEX index_years_on_person_id;

CREATE INDEX index_years_on_person_id
  ON years
  USING btree
  (person_id);
```

Edit: Answer is given at the end of this long (sorry) discussion.

Comment: Please include your related schema and controller in your question.

Comment: I've written a post but no real solution; I'll delete if necessary but more importantly, it would be better if we jumped into chat to get it sorted. If you leave a comment, we can get it fixed

Comment: It might also be an interpolation issue

Comment: Rich. I haven't chatted here, not sure how to implement it. Private or is there a channel. Looks like 8 hours time diff. Therefore might be tomorrow morning my time. -8 GMT

Answer (score 0):

```
undefined method given_name for nil:NilClass
```

This means you're calling `given_name` on an undefined variable. In your case, `person.given_name`

The issue is *either* that you don't have the associated `person` object (IE it doesn't exist), or the associations are not set up correctly.

--

Several steps to debug:

1. Is `person_id` populated?
2. Is your schema set up correctly?

---

The most likely issue is that your `person_id` ([foreign key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key)) value is not present. You'll be able to see this by using the [`rails console`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) to test whether the value is present:

```
$ rails c
$ years = Year.all
$ years.each do |year|
$ - year.person_id
$ end
$ -> output of person_id values
```

If you don't have a value for `person_id`, it will mean that your `Year` cannot associate with the appropriate `Person` (hence your problem). To fix it, you need to make sure you have the [respective foreign keys & objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) present in your db:

```
#app/models/year.rb
class Year < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :address
   belongs_to :person

   validates :person, :address, presence: true
end
```

-

> started wondering about foreign keys

This doesn't seem to be a problem (I checked your migrations):

[image]

The above shows the only foreign keys requires for `has_many :through` should be `address_id` & `person_id` in your `Year` model. You don't need a `foreign_key` in a table unless the `Model` has `belongs_to`.

---

**Update**

The fix was to use [`.try`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try):

```
#app/views/years/index.html.erb
...
  <%= y.person.try(:given_name) %>
```

Comment: Partial output of your suggested console test

    > [#<Year id: 22, year_date: "1887-09-01", created_at: "2016-01-26 22:58:21", updated_at: "2016-01-26 23:00:05", resto: true, resid: false, source: "1888 Los Angeles City Directory. p856 Restaurant s...", person_id: 96, address_id: 134, title: "Proprietor">, #<Year id: 23, year_date: "1887-09-01", created_at: "2016-01-27 05:28:53", updated_at: "2016-01-27 05:28:53", resto: true, resid: false, source: "1888 Los Angeles City Directory. p855",

Comment: So it seems to be pulling the data. Are you sure it doesn't work, even with the above code?

Comment: Here's what show up in the browser:

    undefined method `given_name' for nil:NilClass
    Extracted source (around line #35):
            <td><%= y.year_date %></td>
        <td class="center"><%= y.person_id %></td>
        <td class="given-name"><%= y.person.given_name %></td>

If I comment out the last line, the browser shows in part:

![Page displays correctly and ID is 52](http://knobby.ws//toShare/railsProblem.png)

Thanks again for your help. I know it's something small that's being overlooked. I'll push up my code as it is now.

PS Sorry, the time limit here gets me.

Comment: Are you sure the `given_name` is present in the respective records?

Comment: I ran rake test. Here is an error that seems relevant. These test were generated by Rails. I'm not up to writing tests yet. The next step.


    ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `given_name' for nil:NilClass
                app/views/years/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_years_show_html_erb__969981829392708727_70138521098720'
                test/controllers/years_controller_test.rb:28:in `block in <class:YearsControllerTest>'
            app/views/years/show.html.erb:32:in `_app_views_years_show_html_erb__969981829392708727_70138521098720'

Comment: Re given_name present in respective records. ![Screen shot of table from pgAdmin](http://knobby.ws//toShare/peopleTable.png)

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of the records themselves? You've shown the table structure' what about the data in the table?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102276/discussion-between-greg-and-rich-peck).

Comment: I'm back now if you want to talk

Comment: To summarize:
Year>Show works

`    <p>
    <strong>Given Name:</strong>
    <%= @year.person.given_name %>
    </p>
`

Year>Index does not work
`
    <% @years.each do |y| %>
      <td><%= y.person.given_name %></td>
    <% end %>
`
`y.person` results in `Person:0x007fb2a25f09b8`

where the Year model has `belong_to :address` and Person model has `has_many :years`

Sorry, I can't get the 4 spaces to work for code

Comment: I have no doubt the association works. I think that for some reason, the `given_name` is either not populated, or has some problem at `db` level

Comment: Do you have a github repo I could look at?

Comment: In chat now if you want to talk

Comment: Since it's fixed, you may wish to accept the answer as to not cause confusion in future

Comment: Will do later. I had realized I needed to do that

Comment: Np thanks and just ask on here if you need any more help

Answer (score 0):

Rich Peck came up with a work around. It should have worked as posted which means there is an underlying problem, which me the OP, hopes will be found in time; particularly since in the process of trying to fix it, he's found lots of stuff to fix.

The work around is to use the [method try](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.5/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) where `<td><%= y.person.given_name %></td>` is replaced by `<td><%= y.person.try(:given_name)</td>`. Nothing else was changed.

Thank you Rich.